# Como concatenar um valor de variável php neste caso

Tags: php, html

Boas, estou com dificuldade em concatenar o valor $value['id'] quando o quero passar por referencia no url em frente ao id (onde tem os ??).

O codigo é o seguinte:

```
<td><?= $value['feriasrestantes'] ?></td>
                    <td><a href='editf.php?id=??'> Editar</a></td>
```

Já tentei com as maneiras 'standard' mas não consegui fazer, alguém tem uma solução?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

É so usar o `$value['id']` do mesmo jeito que fez com ferias, mas no ponto onde precisa

Simples assim

```
<td><?= $value['feriasrestantes'] ?></td>
<td><a href="editf.php?id=<?php echo $value['id'] ?>"> Editar</a></td>
```

Usei `echo` so pra ficar mais claro. O lance é que voce pode exibir, `echo` por exemplo, em qualquer lugar do HTML

Comment: Que estupidez, muito obrigado!

Comment: se a resposta te ajudou de alguma maneira, escolha ela como a melhor, assim voce tambem contribui com o site.